# Pull multiple values through a lookup

Tags: workflow, lookup-column

I am rather new with SP so I apologise if I cant express myself too well.
Problem at hand:

Two lists - *Shops* and *Managers* with a many-to-many relationship between them.
I.E. in Shops there can be more than one managers and a manager can manage more than one shop

I want to either:

1. Create a List C where I have a lookup column listing each shop in the first column and in another ALL of the managers that correspond to this shop, written in one line.
2. Insert a column in Shops outlining all of the managers per a particular shop.

Essentially I want to create a workflow that is activated on a specific date, which checks whether there has been any change in the Managers or the Shops list and subsequently update List C.

Any idea on how I can get multiple values for a lookup?
I created the workflow, but I can only have one value per a field in Shops for managers.

Answer (score 0):

You should allow multiple values on lookup column:

[image]

**EDIT:**

This will allow you to enter multiple lookup values in the column:
[image]

Comment: yes I did that, but somehow it still doesn't allow me to have several values! I created different variables and all, but I am stuck with SP showing me only the 1st value

Comment: Please take a look at edited post.

Comment: I think SPD only gets the first value of a multiple value column. You might be able to fetch the multiple values if you use the REST API to query the list item and iterate through the list of multiple values.

Comment: Right, well as mentioned my skills in SP are more of an admin level for now - not much experience with the actual code. But thank! It means that I'm at least certain that none of the easier ways would work

@slaven - do you mind elaborating your 2nd solution a bit?

Comment: It's one solution. First screenshot shows editing a lookup column to allow multiple values and the second screen shows how you can enter multiple values in lookup column when creating new list item or editing existing list item.

Answer (score 0):

The above is basically correct. In your shops list, create a lookup field to your Managers list, but instead of ID, use the title field (I'll assume your managers name is in that field).

```
Get information from 
Managers
In this column
Managers Name
```

When you add a shop, you can select all the managers for that shop.
In workflow, if you return that lookup field, you'll have the option to return it as 'Lookup Values (semicolon delimited)', which will be a list of all the managers.